# Print JSON result using PHP

Tags: php, json

Trying to print records from result received from JSON. Below is the format of JSON result

I am getting in `$result = json_decode($result,true);`

```
Array
(
    [title] => API Directory
    [description] => This directory contains links for Product Feed API and Delta Feed API of all categories with all the versions available
    [apiGroups] => Array
        (
            [affiliate] => Array
                (
                    [name] => affiliate
                    [apiListings] => Array
                        (
                            [food_nutrition] => Array
                                (
                                    [availableVariants] => Array
                                        (
                                            [v0.1.0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [resourceName] => food_nutrition
                                                    [get] => 
                                                    [deltaGet] => 
                                                    [top] => 
                                                    [post] => 
                                                    [put] => 
                                                    [delete] => 
                                                )

                                            [v1.1.0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [resourceName] => food_nutrition
                                                    [get] => 
                                                    [deltaGet] => 
                                                    [top] => 
                                                    [post] => 
                                                    [put] => 
                                                    [delete] => 
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [apiName] => food_nutrition
                                )
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I wanted to print `[resourceName]` and `[get] from [v1.1.0] => Array`
How can I get this done? Please advice.

Comment: Something like `echo $result['apiGroups']['affiliate']['apiListings']['food_nutrition']['availableVariants']['v1.1.0']['resourceName']`?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $result['apiGroups']['affiliate']['apiListings']['food_nutrition']['availableVariants']['v1.1.0']['resourceName'];
echo $result['apiGroups']['affiliate']['apiListings']['food_nutrition']['availableVariants']['v1.1.0']['get'];
```

Not very pretty but something like that anyway, it's a multidimensional array afterall.

Comment: ['food_nutrition'] is not static. There are more nodes for other categories.

Comment: That's like moving the goalposts after someone takes a shot at goal!